# Excel CSV import: QueryTable.FillAdjacentFormulas only works on second refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I'm importing a csv file into Excel using VBA, and need to look up values on another sheet using formulas. The QueryTable is re-created for every refresh.
Even though .FillAdjacentFormulas is set to true, this doesn't work on .Refresh(). Only if I extend the result range and run a second refresh() does it work, which can't be right. 
In the Code below, strFile is a csv file with 7 columns, for copy/paste use this:

```
12345,Some Contact,12345,12345,12345,Something Else,A Description
12346,Some Contact,12346,12346,12346,Something Else again,Another Description
12347,Some Contact,12347,12347,12347,Something Else Entirely,Yet Another Description
```

The procedure is below, slightly shortened for the non-essential parts

```
Public Sub ImportFile()
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = "C:\testfile.csv" ' The test file here.
    ' procedures to reset the used space, select the file etc omitted for brevity
    ' my sheet is called shBacs, and I'm pre-filling the formulas here before loading the text file.
    shBacs.Range("H4").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX(AllCustomers!AllCustomers, MATCH(A4, OFFSET(AllCustomers!AllCustomers, , 1, , 1), FALSE), 1), ""No Customer"")"
    ' more similar statements omitted for brevity
    With shBacs.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=shBacs.Range("A4"))
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        '.PreserveColumnInfo = True ' throws 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error for some reason?
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .Name = "BacsFile"
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = True ' 
        .Refresh ' Formulas are not filled
        shBacs.Names.Add Name:="BacsFile", RefersTo:=.ResultRange.Resize(, .ResultRange.Columns.Count + 6) ' include the formula columns in the result range
        .Refresh ' 2nd refresh fills the adjacent columns; this can't be right
        .Delete ' clean up the QueryTable
    End With    
' error and exit handlers omitted for brevity      
End Sub
```

Any clue as to why the formulas do not fill on the first .Refresh would be appreciated. If you happen to know why PreserveColumnInfo throws a 1004 Run-Time-Error that might help as well...

Comment: 1-try to insert formulas last 2-instead of `range.formula` use `range.value="=blah blah"`

Comment: No change if I use .Value = "=Formula" or .Formula = "=Formula".

Comment: did you try to create the query table first and then insert your formulas?

Comment: Hi @Ibo, no I didn't. In the end, I'd need the result range to put the formulas to the right, which doesn't exist until .Refresh. The question suggests that it won't work unless the query table exists previously?

Comment: Just for testing purposes; I've moved the formula insert to just before .Refresh inside the With QueryTables.Add; no change there. Maybe I have to live with the second refresh.

Comment: add `shBacs.calculate` to force Excel formulas to re-calculate. add it to the end and see what happens

Comment: .calculate doesn't do anything. I begin to think that columns are considered adjacent for existing query tables only.

Comment: if would try to paste the data and clear the query table, you are using VBA after all and you can always get connected and import data from anywhere you want. I guess in that case the data pasted will be considered static data and formulas will work just fine

Comment: if would try to paste the data and clear the query table, you are using VBA after all and you can always get connected and import data from anywhere you want. I guess in that case the data pasted will be considered static data and formulas will work just fine